# How can I send SMS messages like Twitter does?

Tags: sms, messaging

Do all cell companies have open APIs that allow you to send SMS messages like Twitter does?

Do you have to pay to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Many (most?) mobile companies have email gateways allowing you to send an SMS.  For AT&T I believe it's phonenumber@text.att.net, but each provider will have a different address.

Answer (score 5):

This [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway) article summaries it pretty well.  Some cell companies have easy formats.  For example, Verizon uses number@vtext.com.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what country you're in.
In the UK to pay to send - receiving is free.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [messagepub](http://messagepub.com). They provide an easy API so that you can send SMS messages from your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a reliable solution then yes you will have to pay for it, there are some limited free versions.

We used Clickatell with an earlier project http://www.clickatell.com/developers.php

Answer (score 0):

It gets a bit more complicated.   E-mail gateways may work for some carriers, but not others.   As noted, it's based on your cell carrier, what we can the aggregator, and possibly a third-party "intercarrier".   However, it also depends on volume.   If you're just sending the occasional SMS via e-mail, it certainly can work, but, it's occasional in use, and you don't get the confirmations that your phone normally sees.   For volume transfers of messages, you typically need to talk to your carrier about access to their "SMSC gateway".  The SMSC gateway speaks an internet protocol (SMPP) to transfer messages from your app, into the carrier clouds.  It it designed for volume, and you get response codes for your messages.